# How to get sum total of basket items

Tags: sql, laravel

Need some help with adding up the totals of two foreach loops, 1st foreach loads the items in the basket, the next matches the items with the products, I need to get the total of all items in the basket including the quantities

I've tried to use `£{{$product->price * $basket->qty}}` but it only returns the total for the last item in the basket

This is the foreach code:

```
            @foreach(Products::where("id", "=", $basket->product_id)->get() as $product)
            <div class="row cart_items_row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="cart_item d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column align-items-lg-center align-items-start justify-content-start">
                        <div class="cart_item_product d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                            <div class="cart_item_image">
                                <div><img src="https://www.cncspace.co.uk/assets/images/{{$product->cover_photo}}.png" alt=""></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart_item_name_container">
                                <div class="cart_item_name"><a href="#">{{$product->name}}</a></div>
                                <div class="cart_item_edit"><a href="#">Edit Product</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart_item_price">£{{$product->price}}</div>
                        <div class="cart_item_price">{{$basket->colour}}</div>
                        <div class="cart_item_price">{{$basket->qty}}</div>
                        <div class="cart_item_price">£{{$product->price * $basket->qty}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
            @endforeach
```

I tried to get the sum of all the products, multiplied by the quantities, then added together but it only shows the last result in the basket, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried Laravel's Collection sum? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sum

Comment: looking at the code provided your basket seems odd. do you add products to your basket as a relation at all? you should make a basket has many products relation that way you can just add products right to the basket, then you can return the products as a groupBy product id and get the length of each product in the basket that is the same.

Answer (score 0):

i am not seeing the second @foreach statement looking at your code